# Is there any way to filter activities of only followers from Feed Group of type Flat?

Tags: getstream-io

Could you please help me to setup below architecture?

I have created 3 different Feed Groups say `timeline, timeline_images, timeline_videos` with type `Flat` to filter activities based on activity types (blog, image, video). Adding activity to Feed Group based on activity type.

I couldn't be able to filter activities of only followers from specific Feed Group

On follow action, trying to set NEWS_FEEDS as below:

```
    {'timeline':'timeline', 'timeline_aggregated':'timeline_aggregated',
     'timeline_images': 'timeline_images', 'timeline_images_aggregated': 'timeline_images_aggregated',
     'timeline_videos': 'timeline_videos', 'timeline_videos_aggregated': 'timeline_videos_aggregated'}
```

but then follower activity is shown in each Feed Group.

can anyone help me to set a filter like above?

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Your follow syntax seems wrong. Could you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, you are looking to "redistribute" an activity initially added in 'NEWS_FEEDS' feeds, into one of these 'timeline', 'timeline_video' or 'timeline_images' feeds depending on the activity type.

Instead of building follow-relationships between 'NEWS_FEEDS' and every timeline feed group, we suggest you post the activity to the right 'timeline' feed using the TO field when you initially add the activity to the 'NEWS_FEEDS' feed. 
Such as the following :

```
// Add the activity to Eric's feed and to Jessica's notification feed
const activity = {
    actor: 'user:Eric',
    message: "I post a video",
    attachments: [video_reference],
    type: 'video'
    verb: 'tweet',
    object: 'tweet:id',
    to: ['timeline_video:1'],
};

const response = await user_feed_1.addActivity(activity)
```